# Как распаковать многотомный архив резервной копии Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, резервное-копирование, shell, tar, gzip

CMS Bitrix по умолчанию разбивает архив (tar.gz) резервной копи на несколько частей вида:

> site-domain_20160905_231753_full_0356f695.tar.gz.x

где *х* в конце - это номер тома.

Как распаковать такой архив с помощью командной строки Linux?

Comment: Файл restore.php Вам в помощь. Предназначен для развертки битриксовых бэкапов. Не требует установленной CMS.

Comment: @НиколайСарры, это самый простой способ, который легко нагуглить, а если php на машине вообще не установлен?! А архив распаковать нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Для извлечения всех частей архива можно воспользоваться простым скриптом:

```
#/bin/bash

path='./path/' # финальный слеш необходим

list=$(ls $path*.tar.gz)

for file in `ls $path*.tar.gz.*`
    do
        let i++

        if [[ -f $(find $path*.tar.gz.$i) ]]
            then
                echo "file $path*.tar.gz.$i found."
                list="$list $path*.tar.gz.$i"
            else
                echo "file $path*.tar.gz.$i not found!"
        fi
    done

cat $list > full.tar.gz
tar zxf ./full.tar.gz -C $path

# rm -rf $list
```

Пропишите путь к директории с архивом в переменную *path*.

Сделайте файл исполняемым:

```
chmod +x filename
```

И запустите его. Архив будет распакован туда же, где находился изначально, т.е. в директорию *path*

Раскомментируйте последнюю строку чтобы удалить архив-источник после распаковки.